# Matplotlib:scatter and colorbar color don't match

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib plot with a color bar and I cannot figure out how to match the colors of the plot and the color bar.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data ocean.csv', delimiter=';')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(23, 7))
#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(width=1500000,height=1000000, projection='stere',lat_ts=73,lat_0=73,lon_0=127, \
            resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()#fill_color='Blue')
m.fillcontinents(color='red')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(60.,80.,5.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,180.,10.))
#m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='Blues')

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(('Dark2_r'), len(data['river1']))
x, y = m(np.array(data['Long1']), np.array(data['Lat1']))
pic=plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o',vmin=0, vmax=1, s=50, c = data['river1'].map(cmap),)

plt.title('доля речных вод, 2015 ',fontsize='15')
plt.colorbar(pic)
plt.show()
plt.draw()
fig.savefig('1.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

i really can't figure out what the problem is!
how can i match colors between plot and colorbar?  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka8Fy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try replacing your `plt.colorbar(pic)` line with:

```
norm = plt.Normalize(min_val, max_val)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
cbar = fig.colorbar(sm, ax=None, orientation='vertical')
```

Where `min_val` and `max_val` are used to scale the colours - they should match what you've passed to scatter, so try `min_val = data['river1'].min` and similar for `max_val`.

I generally try to pass a [scalar mappable object to colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html) when I'm handling various inputs.